# Вывести массив из MySQL без изменений

Tags: php

Вот наработка:

```
$res = mysql_query("
SELECT  `content`
FROM  `cart`
LIMIT 0 , 100500
");
echo "<br>--".mysql_fetch_array($res)."--<br>";
```

Мне нужно вывести данные в таком виде:

```
Array(

'text1',

'text2',

'text3'
);
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query("
SELECT  `content`
FROM  `cart`
LIMIT 0 , 100500
");

echo '<pre>Array(' . PHP_EOL; // "Array("
if( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM) ){
    echo "'" . $row[0] . "'"; // первая строка
}
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM) ){
    echo ',' . PHP_EOL . "'" . $row[0] . "'"; // ",", перевод строки, след. строка
}
echo PHP_EOL . ');</pre>'; // перевод строки, ");"
mysql_free_result($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=mysql_query('SELECT `content` FROM  `cart` LIMIT 0 , 100500');// делаем выборку из таблицы

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))// берем результаты из каждой строки
 $a[]= $row['content'].'</p>';// выводим данные
var_dump($a);
```

Зы, извращение писать **LIMIT 0 , 100500** если уж все записи нужны то не писать и вовсе :)

А в чем смысл этого запроса тогда???

Comment: Shrek, Вы неправильно меня поняли. Мне не нужно вывести так:
text1
text2
text3
Мне нужно вывести все **именно** в таком виде:
<code>Array(

'text1',

'text2',

'text3'
);</code>

Comment: обновил ответ.

Comment: Тоже выводится по-другому. Примерно так же, как и у Ring. Ответ тоже примерно такой...

Comment: Ты понимаешь что 

>array('text1','text2','text3');

При выводе его через **print_r()** или **var_dump()** он выводит и индексы, показывая тем самым в какой именно части массива что лежит, а просто извращаться и выводить как тебе нужно тогда тебе к ответу [kite](http://hashcode.ru/questions/79627#79643)  но ЭТО ПОЛНЫЙ ИЗВРАТ, простите меня люди добрые. что программисты дошли до того что им нужно так вот извращаться *пойду плакать*

Comment: @Shrek, я ответил на вопрос "как". Ответ на вопрос "зачем", по определению, должен знать тот, кто спрашивает.

Comment: @Kite да-да-да, я с тобой не спорю, я просто и дал ссыль на твой ответ, он на 100% подходит, просто мне уже интересно зачем оно такое нужно?!

Comment: Понятия не имею. Похоже на генерацию JavaScript-массива средствами PHP. Но, в этом случае, обычно, используют JSON.

Comment: KiTE, совершенно верно, это извращение - генерация js массива. :)

Comment: С JSON никогда не работал, поэтому и не знаю даже чего спрашивать здесь...

Comment: @nick777, в JavaScript констукция типа:

    var a = new Array('one', 'two');

эквивалентна:

    var a = ['one', 'two'];

Второй вариант - это JSON. [Тут][1] пордробнее.

  [1]: http://javascript.ru/Array

Answer (score 0):

В таком-же виде? ^_^

```
$res = mysql_query("
  SELECT  `content`
  FROM  `cart`
  LIMIT 0 , 100500
");
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
  $array[]  = $row;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Тогда выводится вот так:
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => text1
            [content] => text2
        )
</pre>
В общем, похоже, так мне не решить эту проблему. Буду думать над другими способами...